# Stuck in fastboot, unable to access recovery or system (oneplus 3)

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, fastboot, oneplus-3

I've clearly done something stupid and desperately need your help!

I have a brand new OnePlus 3T that I've managed to get stuck in a bootloop. I can access fastboot but no recovery or system. OEM is unlocked.

Things I have done:

1. Tried to install TWRP recovery. Fastboot says this was successful, but I haven't been able to boot into it.
2. Tried booting directly to TWRP recovery img. This freezes the phone and it says FAILED (too many links) in fastboot
3. Tried installing stock OP3 recovery. Same problem as before.
4. Tried hard brick recovery tool. Everything lights up green with installed:ok but still I'm stuck in this bloody bootloop.
5. Tried installing ColorOS through the Chinese install tool. Comes up Failed every time.

I am at my absolute wits end trying to sort this out and I literally have no idea what to do. I have been Googling this all morning to no avail.

Any help anyone can give whatsoever would be really, really appreciated.

EDIT: Some additional info from fastboot screen -

PRODUCT_NAME - msm8996 
VARIANT - MTP UFS 
BOOTLOADER VERSION - [EMPTY] 
BASEBAND VERSION - [EMPTY] 
SERIAL NUMBER - b2411609 
SECURE BOOT - enabled 
DEVICE STATE - unlocked

EDIT 2: more weirdness. I changed the USB cable from a micro USB with USB-C adapter to the proper USB-C that came in the box, and the phone booted into the OS. I tried to download the latest Oxygen update via the software update tool but that just boots me back into fastboot.

EDIT 3: I think it's just my recovery partition that's busted. Tried reinstalling stock recovery and that didn't work, so currently I have fastboot and OS but with no recovery - given that this is a separate issue I'll do some research before asking further questions.

@EHH - thanks for helping me figure this out. Really appreciate your time :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133558/discussion-on-question-by-rozzlemcfrozzle-stuck-in-fastboot-unable-to-access-re).

Answer (score 1):

Boot loop was resolved by using the USB-C cable provided by OP, however the recovery partition seems to be corrupted. Phone works though so nbd, recovery can be sorted out later on.